# CSS doesn't do its thing when using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, css

I'm learning about PHP classes and objects right now so to get some experience with it, I'm converting my site using these instead of static html to save me typing the same generic html over and over again.

So, this is part of the object:

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/main.css\" />
```

...which produces this in the browser (after I changed the root directory in the Apache config file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/wamp/www/test/main.css" />
```

My problem is that the styling in that css file isn't showing on the page. If I copy the location of the css file shown in the browser (when clicking 'view source') and enter it into the url bar, the css file appears. So if I can access it this way, why can't the webpage access it? I'm assuming it has something to do with permissions but if I right-click on the css file in my file browser, it says that everything can at least read it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you ever expose the document root to the client?

Comment: @Ignacio Does the client see that? I thought $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was processed on the server and that then pumped out the static html?

Comment: @Dan No, it simply substitutes whatever value is currently at that index in the `$_SERVER` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself some effort. This works just as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css" media="all" />
```

This assumes, of course, that the CSS file is in the document root.

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping if I could use document root, I'd be able to just implement that line in every page on my site rather than adjusting the directory for every page.

Comment: @Dan That will not need to be adjusted. It is essentially an absolute reference to the document root.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow here. Once I'm a few folders down, for example: /folder/morefolder/anotherfolder/file.html ...I'd have to reference the css file like so: ../../../main.css - right? I'd rather not have to add the ../'s - same goes for menu links on this page too.

Comment: If your site is at http://example.com and the CSS file is at http://example.com/main.css, you can always refer to it with `/main.css` and it'll work no matter where you are in the directory structure.

Comment: @Dan Doesn't matter, adding a `/` at the beginning tells the server "Start at the document root". So `/main.css` will work from anywhere on your site (again, assuming that `main.css` is at the top level of your document root).

Comment: @Dan Nope. As @Juhana said, `/` IS the document root. You don't have to take my word for it. Try it on your server... :]

Comment: Oh wow. I had no idea about that. I can't believe I over-looked something so basic. Thanks so much for that guys :D

Comment: Does this not work with.php files or something. I get the error: `Warning: require(/class_lib.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\contact\index.php on line 3` when I run this: `require("/class_lib.php");`

Comment: @Dan Shouldn't. I've used that syntax. It looks like you're doing this locally? I seem to remember having troubles with paths in Apache on a local machine. I do something similar to this: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-define-global-absolute-path-in-php/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work locally or on the server. I'm going to just use relative paths instead.

Comment: @Tieson T Actually, `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/class_lib.php");` works - are there any drawbacks to using this? Someone on this question said "Why would you ever expose the document root to the client?"...

Comment: @Dan You can do that for `include` (and `require`, and pretty much any PHP method that acts on file paths), since that all happens on the server, when the server is parsing and executing your PHP scripts. If you use the same thing in an `href` or `src` that value will be echoed out as part of the actual HTML output. That means the browser will try to resolve your server path locally, which should fail. A less-than-scrupulous person might take advantage of knowing your site directories...

Comment: @Dan Absolute paths work. It's what I do: http://geeksneversleep.com/ -> check the source.

Comment: @Tieson T. Absolute paths are working for me for the menu links and css link but not the include where put in the `/` creates a relative path. It's okay, I'll just use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` for the includes ;) Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Everything I seem to write at the moment is wrong. Nothing ever works first time but hey, I'm sure I'll get better :D

Answer (score 0):

What if someone else visits your page, and hasn't got a file named `"C:/wamp/www/test/main.css"`? ;-) I guess the implementation differs per browser, but a site shouldn't be able to access resources on the visitor's computer this way.

You want to use either the website name (obtainable through `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'`), or an absolute URL (`/test/main.css`) and set the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in a `<base href>` element.

Comment: I like the sound of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. These files are currently on my local web server. Once I've uploaded them to my actual web server, the location of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will change, right?

Comment: @Dan Yes, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is specific to the server the pages are being served from. Also, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the local path on the server Apache starts looking for files. Therefore, if you use that, nobody will be able to access the files (as you found out for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You reach web sites though URLs (`http://example.com/foo/bar`), not through their path in the server's hard disc (`C:\www\example\htdocs\foo\bar\index.html`). This applies to everything: documents, pictures... and style sheets.

You don't really need to take the web root from a PHP variable unless you are planning to change it. Most of the times, you can hard-code `/` happily. I suggest the compromise of creating your own constant:

define('WEB_ROOT', '/');

?>