# Unable to link css file using constant

Tags: php, css, constants

I am trying to include css file with php so that i have one same path through my sub folders and files as well. This is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ROOT;?>CustomStyles/MyStyles.css">
```

I have constant root set up before in this way:

```
define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

However this does not work because the result of the link is that after ROOT constant there is the web address of my server.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens instead?

Comment: The css file is not inncluded because the link to the file contains the url address of server in the middle between <?=ROOT;?> and CustomStyles/MyStyles.css

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle"? What does `ROOT` really contain? If it should contain something different, why not use another constant or variable? Can you share the resulting markup of that line?

Comment: Basically this is the result of the link of css file: /nfsmnt/hostinw2351/1/e/1e3439b1-4983-4437-adf9-4982hdj2023/mynewwebsite.eu/web/CustomStyles/MyStyles.css>

mynewwebsite.eu is the cause of the problem

Comment: It will never work @Rudolf. You have to leave `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.
In the place of that, you have to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: use: <?php
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/";
define('ROOT', $link );
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ROOT;?>CustomStyles/MyStyles.css">

Comment: This doesn’t need an absolute URI, just use relative URLs that start with a `/` and you are good to go.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307052/css-doesnt-do-its-thing-when-using-serverdocument-root

Comment: after usin $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] this is in the html
mynewwebsite.eu/CustomStyles/MyStyles.css" but it still does not work. However when i open the same link in browser it shows me the css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your css file in public directory. Example assets/. And link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//your.site/assets/MyStyles.css">
```

Comment: I have it under public directory www/CustomStyles folder.

Comment: This won't work as you should not use a double slash in the beginning - the current code will try to contact the host `assets`

Comment: href="//your.site/assets/MyStyles.css"

Comment: putting // in front of the link worked, Thank you very much